# Up to Date Tweet-Script for PHP

Tags: php, twitter

Since Twitter uses oAuth there are a lot of tweet-scripts for php floating around the web. And most of them don't work because they're simply out of date.

I have now been looking over 3 hours just for a simple "send a message to twitter via php"-script. And I did not found one that works good. I don't need more than just a simple PHP-Script that lets me tweet a message.

Please help me out! :/

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that there isn't something on the [Twitter Development Talk](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk) list for this.

Answer (score 0):

I use the twitteroauth library located here:

https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION

Step 9 mentions how to do a status update. As for the token / token secret, if you check your app's page on dev.twitter.com, it gives you a developer token / token secret to use if you're the only one controlling the app.

Comment: I am now stuck at 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.' I have entered the correct CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET, Type: Browser and the right CALLBACK URL.

Comment: @Hans is this a web app or a php console app?

Comment: Okay, now I see an stdClass Object array. It shows my Twitter data. So this means I finally got it?

Comment: If you the response you got from status/update matches the tweet that you sent, then yes it's setup correctly. You can check that by wrapping a print_r() around the status/update call.

Comment: Well great, Twitter is over capacity right while I am trying :-(

Comment: @Hans First off you will need to make sure that token and token secret are accessible when you make the calls. What most web apps do is store the token / token secret in a database and tie it to a user. Then when the user logs in, they pull the values and store them in the session.